# HTML5 Mobile Game CSS

Tags: html, cross-browser, html5-canvas

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Game</title>

    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
      body, html {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      #canvas {
        position: absolute;
      }
    </style>

    <!-- <meta charset="utf-8" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> -->
    <!-- <meta charset="utf-8"> -->
    <!-- <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" /> -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas">
      Your browser needs to support canvas to play this game!
    </canvas>

    <!-- Include libraries -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pentagine/build/pentagine.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cp.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include game classes -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/MenuState.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Block.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Constants.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ScoreState.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/PlayState.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The relevant lines are the CSS and these ones:

```
<!-- <meta charset="utf-8" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> -->
<!-- <meta charset="utf-8"> -->
<!-- <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" /> -->
```

I want to make my Canvas occupy as much screen as there is to occupy. I want my canvas to be full screen and this used to be working fine both on Firefox, Chromium and Firefox OS, but now it doesn't seem to be working on any. I need help with figuring out the CSS and `content=""` tags to make the canvas (and therefore canvas's `context.width` and `context.height` occupy as much space as there is.

Comment: why is your canvas position:absolute? Just remove that and give it width:100%; height:100%

Comment: You should do some research before you ask a question

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AwLwF/

CSS:

```
body {
   position:relative;
}
canvas {
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   top:0;
}
```

JS:

```
$("canvas").width($(document).width());
$("canvas").height($(document).height());
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas-element").getContext("2d");
function draw() {
    //draw here
    ctx.fillStyle="blue";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,200,100);
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
draw();
```

BUT there is little problem. Aspect Ratio. Strange resolutions will destroy scale of drawn elements.

Answer (score 0):

That should make the canvas full screen in CSS (not tested, but works for divs so you should be fine with canvas too):

```
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

In javascript you could read the window/document width/height and add it to the canvas to calculate with it. Like this in jQuery:

```
$(document).height();
$(document).width();
```

And like this without jQuery:

```
document.width;
document.height;
```

I really hope that'll be a help for you.

Comment: You should set the `width` and `height` to `100%`, auto doesn't automatically take up the full space. Using CSS's comma notation you could use the code he already has for `body`